# TextInputLayout will not set errorIconDrawable

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

When I use `style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"` for `TextInputLayout`, setting `app:errorIconDrawable` does nothing. It only works when I don't set the style and let it inherit the application theme (`Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`). `app:endIconDrawable` also doesn't work and I cannot find an alternative/solution to this problem. Please help!

---

The following works while inheriting the application theme:`Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` but I don't want this style, particularly the underline doesn't align with the texts:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_password_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="username"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/login_password_input_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

---

This uses the style that I need but will not show the error icon:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_password_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="username"
    style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/login_password_input_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using the legacy style `Widget.Design.TextInputLayout` it doesn't have support for all text field features that the `*.OutlinedBox` and `*.FilledBox` styles have.

You can't set the `errorIconDrawable` in the xml and you have to call `TextInputLayout.setErrorIconDrawable` after `TextInputLayout.setError`.

```
login_password_input_layout.setError("Error text!!");                
login_password_input_layout.setErrorIconDrawable(R.drawable....);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hmm, see if you use directly below

> ```
> style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"
> ```

then your error drawable becomes null.

What I would suggest you is, create a style, modify the values as you like

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#f32</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#4CAF50</item>
    <item name="errorIconDrawable">@drawable/ic_baseline_error_24</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#E91E63</item>
    <item name="errorEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

and then apply it to via

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_password_input_layout"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:hint="username"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password_input_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This should solve.